# Ant with JUnit task - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: ant, junit, out-of-memory

I have an interesting problem. I am using Ant which executes JUnit tests (test suite composed with 50 tests) via  build.xml element. The problem is that I receive OutOfMemoryError.

I have enlarged heap space using ANT_OPTS arguments but it did not help. When I execute the same test suite in Eclipse - everything is fine - memory is released thanks to GC.

I think that this problem is related to Ant and its JUnit task.

Maybe logging of the tests are the reason(but on the other hand I have printsummary="false", [maybe outputtoformatters should be set to false as well???]).

My second guess is that TEST***.xml file (generated at the end of the test) is held in memory and flushed at the end of the test. Is there any way to reduce logs which are in that file?

Guys, please give me some clues.

Comment: Narrow down you problem. Start with just one junit test (comment out all the others) and see what happens.

Comment: When suite contains one test - everything is fine. Only big suites cause the problem.

Comment: could you post the actual code snippet?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182746/junitreport-ant-task-giving-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to sum up I want to say that the root of the problems was logging. Logs were sent to the stream and not flushed. After switching the logs off - everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the maxmemory attribute in the junit task.  See the [Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Comment: I've already tried it. maxmemory option works only when fork="true". It did not give any effect. Any more ideas?

Comment: Hmm - can you post the stack trace from the exception you're getting ?  You might be running out of something other than heap space, such as PermGen space.

Comment: No, it is not PermGen. I have set the space of PermGen to the value of 256m.

Comment: OK - if you won't post the stack trace as everyone has asked, it's hard to help more.

Answer (score 0):

By default the fork mode is off. Please try with fork mode on and forkmode set to [pertest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Comment: I think that it will not help. I have @Suite runner with 50 tests. Such a bunch is treated as a single test - one TEST-xxx.xml report file. I think that report generation will be performed within that forked JVM so it will give no effect. Any more ideas?

Comment: @ Lucas Smith : please post the final ant file content and exception stack trace.